# creating a boolean array which compares numpy elements to None

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, numpy

I have a numpy array with dtype=object, and I want to create a boolean array identifying which elements are `None`. But it looks like `None` behaves differently...

```
a = np.array(['Duck','Duck','Duck','Goose',None,1,2,3,1,3,None,4])
print a == 'Duck'
print a == 3
print a == None
```

which results in

```
[ True  True  True False False False False False False False False False]
[False False False False False False False  True False  True False False]
False
```

Is there an "numpythonic" way to get a boolean array of the `None` elements? I can use

```
np.array([x is None for x in a])
```

but this seems like there should be a better way.

Comment: I *definitely* would not have expected ndarrays to behave differently for `None`... good catch!

Comment: ...especially because of this quote from the NumPy docs: *"Each of the arithmetic operations (+, -, *, /, //, %, divmod(), ** or pow(), <<, >>, &, ^, |, ~) and the comparisons (==, <, >, <=, >=, !=) is equivalent to the corresponding universal function (or ufunc for short) in Numpy."* I can only assume the `np.equal` is the ufunc for `==`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.equal`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.equal.html):

```
In [20]: np.equal(a, None)
Out[20]: 
array([False, False, False, False,  True, False, False, False, False,
       False,  True, False], dtype=bool)
```

Comment: This is definately a good workaround, but do you know why it doesn't work for `None`?  The numpy docs say that `==` should match it's ufunc equivalent, and I imagine the `equal` is the matching ufunc.

Comment: @SethMMorton Found a related ticket on Github: [`== None` seems to do `is None` for the array instead of returning element-wise comparison #3759](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/3759)

Comment: Awesome... I guess that solves the why (it's a bug).  Thanks!

Comment: Comparison with `== None` should give a `FutureWarning: comparison to 'None' will result in an elementwise object comparison in the future.` in current version. `None` is the only exception where this happens, but that will get fixed.